# how to handle <a href="sms://"> in my own webview?

Tags: android

I have a WebView that loads a page that have links that contain "sms:// or tel://". Im trying to create an intent filter that will launch another activity when an user clicks one of these links. For some reason my activity that i created to handle this links is not being called.

This is the intent filter that i try to create.

```
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
 <data android:scheme="tel" android:host="path" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind figure it out. 
simple mistake.

```
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="tel"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle this is to create a WebClient for your Webview. This will then allow you to use shouldOverrideUrlLoading() to check each url clicked. Then if url begins with tel: or sms: you are able to redirect to a new intent.

```
if(url.startsWith("tel:")){
Intent telIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
      startActivity(telIntent);
      return true; 
}
```

[Webview "mailto:" link & "tel:" link work using Intent.ACTION_VIEW, but how do I add unique Subject ie for "mailto:" link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578719/webview-mailto-link-tel-link-work-using-intent-action-view-but-how-do-i)